# Search within a piece of code in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio. I wrote a code in html for javadoc of my android project. In html code, the count of { is 36 and } is 37. So I wanted to search usages of these 2 symbols only in html code to balance the braces. Is there anyway I can do it?
I appreciate your help.!!

Comment: Select the code you want to search by holding down your left mouse button. Then go to Edit-Find. You will search inside the selected text.

Comment: Thanks @Lazaros Papadopoulos. But I don't think that how it works. It simply searches the selected text in entire file.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, read my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search within a text, after you have selected your text in the editor, go to menu: Edit -> Find -> Find in Path -> Scope: select Custom, Selection.

Comment: It worked but didn't solve my problem as it has some problem searching '{' in the selection whereas no problem in searching for '}'

Comment: Thanks anyways @Lazaros Papadopoulos